# How to say out letters in PlainText mode?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Most of my speech output are simple text so I am using `type: "PlainText"` for my responses.

Is there a way to read out individual letters without resorting to SSML?

I tried "'I' 'D'" for Id but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these (they sound good to me in alexa en voices). Tested in https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/test//en_US/: "Voice and tone".

ay,
    bee,
    see,
    dee,
    ee,
    eff,
    gee,
    aitch,
    aye,
    jay,
    kay,
    el,
    em,
    en,
    oh,
    pee,
    queue,
    are,
    ess,
    tee,
    ewe,
    vee,
    double u,
    ex,
    why,
    zee